# Freezing a physics simulation and use a certain frame to go on with modelling

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, keyframes

I am just modelling a small cup that I want to fill with sugar cubes. To make it look more realistic, I want to let the cubes drop into the cup. I have already physics enabled and the right collisions but I am just wondering how to freeze a single frame to take it as my initial frame. Everytime I switch back to the first frame, I lose my keyframe and the cubes are over the cup again.

I guess the answer is pretty easy but I couldn't find it in the manual yet.

Comment: I think you mean the 'Apply transformation' button in the physics tab in the toolbar of 3D view? :)

Comment: @FacebFaceb yep, that was what I was looking for. I just noticed I have different physics options when I change my Render Engine. How does it affect my Simulation?

Also there is a difference in the simulation if I hit "p" or "play" on the timeline in the blender game engine. Do you know why?

Comment: When you press the play button on the timeline, then the simulation is quite the same in all engines. But it makes a difference when you press 'p' in bge, because the settings are different (such as the damping, bounciness and friction), if I'm correct